# How to dynamically map ClaimType from string stored in SQL

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, claims

I have a `UserClaims` table in a SQL DB. The table stores `Id` (int), `UserId` (int - FK), `Type` (nvarchar), and `Value` (nvarchar). The Foreign Key maps to the `Id` on the `User` table. I am currently using Dapper to pull records out of the DB.

When retrieving the `UserClaims` for a specific `User`, I would like to have the code be "future-proofed" so that, if I add already defined `UserClaims` (based on the `ClaimTypes` static class in `System.Security.Claims`), they will map out and can be referred to elsewhere in the code "natively".

The goal would be to have code like this be functional (obviously this isn't working):

```
foreach(var c in user.UserClaims)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Type))
    {
        if (c.Type == "Role")
            authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, c.Value));
        else
        {
            var _type = typeof(ClaimTypes);
            var field = _type?.GetField(c.Type);

            if (field != null)
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(field, c.Value));
            else
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(c.Type, c.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, if I can map the `Type` coming from the DB to one of the fields in `ClaimTypes`, then I want to use that field. If not, then I can create a custom Claim Type that I will need to write some handler for.

`Role` was an easy `ClaimType` to map, and I could continue that pattern, or possibly implement a switch to map more well-known types, but I was hoping I could leverage the already-existing functionality more cleanly by mapping back to the `ClaimTypes` based on their name.

Examples:

```
    authClaims.Add(new Claim(field, c.Value));
    // could be equivalent to something like:               
    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "United States"));
    // stored in the UserClaims table as:
    // 5, 1, 'Country', 'United States' -- OR --
    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, "+11234567890"));
    // 6, 1, 'MobilePhone', '+11234567890'
```

Comment: Do you want Extend or add custom claims using IClaimsTransformation ? A ClaimsIdentity is created to add the new claims and this can be added to the ClaimsPrincipal. You can have a look at [Mapping, customizing, and transforming claims in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation).

Comment: @QingGuo, I'll add better examples to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code

```
var field = _type?.GetField(c.Type);
```

into

```
 var field = _type?.GetField(c.Type)?.GetValue(null).ToString();
```

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

```
    var UserClaims = new List<UserClaims>() { 
    new UserClaims() { Type="Country",Value= "United States" },
    new UserClaims() { Type="CC",Value= "C1" }
};
var authClaims = new List<Claim>();
foreach (var c in UserClaims)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Type))
    {
            var _type = typeof(ClaimTypes);
            var field = _type?.GetField(c.Type)?.GetValue(null).ToString();

            if (field != null)
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(field, c.Value));
            else
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(c.Type, c.Value));
       
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I was so close, but so far...